# change "out of stock" text with html element woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i want to change  the "out of stock" text with html element woocommerce.
Currently, I'm using:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'change_out_of_stock_text', 1, 2);
function change_out_of_stock_text( $availability, $_product ) {
    global $post;

    if ( ! $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $out_of_stock = "Out of Stock";
        if(get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_field', true )!="") {
            $out_of_stock = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_field', true );
        }
         $availability['availability'] = __($out_of_stock, 'woocommerce');
    }
    return $availability;
}
```

It can change the "Out of Stock" text with the value from custom input field i made in product page but i want to show the html element from that value to shop page as well. For example if the value is 'Sold out', it should output the link text as well "Sold out".

I also tried woocommerce_stock_html but it got the same problem:

```
function change_out_of_stock_text( $html, $_availability, $_product ){
    global $post;
    $out_of_stock = "Out of Stock";
    $_availability = $_product->get_availability();

    if(get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_field', true )!="") {
        $out_of_stock = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_field', true );
    }

    $html = '<p class="stock ' . esc_attr( $_availability['class'] ) . '">' . $out_of_stock . '</p>';
    return $html;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_stock_html', 'change_out_of_stock_text', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you have the right idea but you are't targeting the appropriate filter which is `woocommerce_get_availability`

```
function so_34126704_availability( $array, $product ){
    if ( ! $_product->is_in_stock() ) && ( $status = get_post_meta( $product->id, '_text_field', true ) ) != "" ){
        $availability['availability'] = $status;
    } 
    return $array;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'so_34126704_availability', 10, 2 );
```

to filter the output html you need to filter `woocommerce_stock_html`. it's a bit half-baked because I don't know what you'd want to do with the classes or where you are linking to, but here's a shell example of that:

```
function so_34126704_availability_html( $html, $_availability, $product ) {
    $availability      = $product->get_availability(); // for some reason the $_availability does not pass the entire array, only the availability key
    $status = get_post_meta( $product->id, '_text_field', true );

    $html = '<p class="stock ' . esc_attr( $availability['class'] ) . '"><a href="#somewhere"/>' . esc_html( $status ) . '</a></p>';

    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_stock_html', 'so_34126704_availability_html', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: still have the same problem: output html as text not as html

Comment: Oh, then maybe you should be filtering [`woocommerce_stock_html`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php#L35) instead?

Comment: Thank you Helga but it still outputs the html text instead of html object (remove esc_html or not still got the same). In my plugin, get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_field', true ) contains the html string so i want to output all of them as html tag.